# Show data with Rapheal on click

Tags: raphael

I am hoping to use Raphael to draw a map and colour code according to a result for an area. That bit I can do. What I would like to do is if the user clicks an area that somewhere additional data appears. Is this possible. Within each element in the Raphael JS file, can I include a data source?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are after, as it depends where the original data is, you could look into http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data but you would have to populate it from somewhere. You really need to show some code if you want more precise useful answers.